# Outlook: How to access other contact folders?

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts, mapi

Some people have a number of lists/folders in Outlook, under Contacts (e.g. besides Contacts and Suggested Contacts, people can add new "folders" of contacts).

Now, my questions:

1. How can I get a list of all these lists/folders?
2. How can I access all the contacts in any of these folders?

I know that if I want to access the contacts from the main "Contacts" list, then the code looks like this:

```
   MAPIFolder oMAPIFolder = 
              oNmSpc.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
   oItemsTemp = oMAPIFolder.Items;
```

How would it look like when accessing other contact lists/folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the "Suggested Contacts" Folder proceed exactly as you do for contact but

Instead of

```
outlook := CreateOLEObject('Outlook.Application');
  NameSpace := outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
  ContactsRoot := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) ;
```

Use

```
outlook := CreateOLEObject('Outlook.Application');
  NameSpace := outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
  SuggestedContactsRoot := NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSuggestedContacts);
```

Where **olFolderSuggestedContacts** has a value of 30 (decimal) or $0000001E in Hexadecimal

I know this is Delphi language, but adapatation to C# should be straightforward.

Comment: Ok. But how do you list other folders with contacts in them?

Comment: You will need to recursively loop through all child folders (MAPIFolder.Folders) starting with the Namespace.Folders collection (returns top level folders of all stores).